# Turn off zsh completion of users everywhere

Tags: linux, shell, autocomplete, zsh

I work on a system with about 60k users. I use `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh`. Autocompletion is mostly great, but periodically it tries to autocomplete with the name of a user on the system. This hangs my shell for 2-3 seconds. It often tries to complete with a username, even if it's expecting something like a path. It happens frequently in a variety of different commands.

It's very frustrating.

I've tried to turn it off with:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:user' ignored-patterns '*'
```

but it didn't work (I tried testing it with `su TAB` and it hung for the normal 2-3 seconds).

I want to stop `zsh` from ever trying to autocomplete with a username anywhere. All of the solutions I see online involve turning it off on a command-by-command basis, which I'd rather not bother with, because there will never be a situation where I want `zsh` to complete with a user.

Can this be done?

Comment: Just from the body of the function `_users`, you want to ignore `users`, not `user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work in most cases:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' users
```

(i.e. provide the empty list as the list of users to draw from) although I've seen usernames pop up once or twice since then.